# Is there a way (or code more specifically) in R to make a new column in the dataset with existing data?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a new column from existing data with the mutate() function. The new column is called "Weight", and is going to show if the acoustic tag ID has weight 1, 2 or 3 (3 different weights). There are 3 different protocols (71kHz, 67kHz and 69kHz), and each weight number belongs to the respective protocol.

Here is the code i am trying to use. Is there something wrong here?

```
mutate(Weight = case_when("71kHz"(Protocol)~"1"
                            "69kHz"(Protocol)~"2",
                            "67kHz"(Protocol)~"3"))
```

Comment: answering your question, one comma is missing after the first line of your code.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the problem!